# Keycloak redirect to login page after login due to Samesite issue

Tags: angular, spring-boot, keycloak, samesite

I have a project that uses are angular(12), spring boot(2.2.0) and keycloak(16).

After the update to the latest Firefox version I am getting redirect to login page after login due to

> "Samesite attribute here error logs on console is "Samesite attribute
> is not provided so default attribute is Samesite = lax".

Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 4):

I have experienced similar issue; there seems to be a bug with the Keycloak angular adapter detecting (in the last Firefox version) that the 3rd party cookies are being blocked. If the Keycloak angular adapter would have detected it correctly, it would have disable the hidden iframe that is used to detect if a Single-Sign Out has occurred.

From what I have seen, you can 1) allowed those cookies for the your url; or 2) Use another browser; or 3) set the configuration option `checkLoginIframe: false` in your Keycloak angular adapter.

See the [official documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#session-status-iframe) to understand the consequences of the third option.

> By default, the JavaScript adapter creates a hidden iframe that is
> used to detect if a Single-Sign Out has occurred. This does not
> require any network traffic, instead the status is retrieved by
> looking at a special status cookie. This feature can be disabled by
> setting checkLoginIframe: false in the options passed to the init
> method.